# CheckBoxFor failing to bind to complex object (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

After checking boxes and submitting the form, the ShouldSend field is the default value (false) in the Controller post method, even if I checked the appropriate box to make it true. I've looked up similar issues, and the two most common recommendations are to check that:

1. the complex objects are indexed so the model binder can put them back together in the list
2. I use CheckBoxFor in order to bind the result of the checkbox to my model

I'm currently doing both of those things, but it's still not binding. Everything else is binding just fine (the list of MessageTypeViewModels in SidebarViewModel, for example).

Any idea why my checkboxes aren't binding?

**ViewModels**

```
public class WrapperViewModel
{
    public WrapperViewModel()
    {
        Sidebar = new SidebarViewModel();
        Content = new ContentViewModel();
    }

    public SidebarViewModel Sidebar { get; set; }
    public ContentViewModel Content { get; set; }
}

public class SidebarViewModel
{
    public SidebarViewModel()
    {
        MessageTypeViewModels = new List<MessageTypeViewModel>
        {
            new TypeViewModel {Type = "Type 1", Label = "Label 1"},
            new TypeViewModel {Type = "Type 2", Label = "Label 2"},

            // etc.
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<MessageTypeViewModel> MessageTypeViewModels { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public int? Field3 { get; set; }
}

public class MessageTypeViewModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSend { get; set; }
}
```

**Views**

```
// Index.cshtml
@model MessageGeneratorViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendMessages", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "content",
}))
{
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h3>Message Types</h3>
        <ul>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MessageTypeViewModels, "MessageTypeEditorTemplate")
        </ul>

        <h3>Target</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field2)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field2)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Field3)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field3)
            </li>
        </ul>

        <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
    </div>
}

// MessageTypeEditorTemplate.cshtml
@model List<MessageTypeViewModel>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <li>
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].ShouldSend)
            @Model[i].Label
        </label>
    </li>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult SendMessages(WrapperViewModel model)
{
    // model.Sidebar.MessageTypeViewModels[<any-index>].ShouldSend is false, even if I checked the appropriate box.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I should have been posting the SidebarViewModel, not the WrapperViewModel. Now everything binds correctly.

```
public ActionResult SendMessages(SidebarViewModel sidebar)
{
    // do stuff
}
```